# Skiping Multiple sheets in a Workbook

Tags: excel, vba

I need a code for skipping Multiple worksheets and go to the next sheet in excel

I tried using select case and if array but it won't work

```vb
Sub s()

    Select Case Sheet
        Case Is = "Weekly Spread (%),Weekly spread (Count)Summary,Sheet1,Consolidated_Data"
        Case Else
             t = 0
             Sheet.Select
             If t = 1 Then
                 Range("a1").Select
                 Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight).End(xlDown)).Copy
             Else
                 Range("a2").Select
                 Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight).End(xlDown)).Copy
             End If
            
             Sheets("LoginData").Select
             If t = 1 Then
                 Range("a1").Select
                 Selection.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
             Else
                 Range("A1").Select
                 Selection.End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0).Select
                 Selection.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
             End If
       
    End Select
    t = t + 1
    
End Sub
```

Comment: is anything wrong with this code

Comment: I'm guessing it should be `Select Case Sheet.Name` and next line `Case "Weekly Spread (%)", "Weekly spread (Count)Summary", "Sheet1", "Consolidated_Data"`

Comment: Also you have `t = 0`  then `If t = 1 Then` which it will never be.

Comment: it won't worked

Comment: i need to loop through after a specific worksheets

Comment: is `Sheets("LoginData").Select` correct ? It is not in the Case statement so is copying to itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Code changed assuming you want to iterate the sheets on the current workbook. I think you need to add LoginData to the list to avoid copying data from the same sheet.

```
Sub s()
    For Each Sheet In ThisWorkbook.Sheets
        Select Case Sheet.Name
            ' I think yo need to add LoginData to this list to avod copying into itself
            Case "Weekly Spread (%)", "Weekly spread (Count)Summary", "Sheet1", "Consolidated_Data"
            Case Else
                 t = 0
                 Sheet.Select
                 If t = 1 Then   'Why the difference here? I do understand it in the paste but not here
                     Range("a1").Select
                     Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight).End(xlDown)).Copy
                 Else
                     Range("a2").Select
                     Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight).End(xlDown)).Copy
                 End If
                
                 Sheets("LoginData").Select
                 If t = 1 Then
                     Range("a1").Select
                     Selection.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
                 Else
                     Range("A1").Select
                     Selection.End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0).Select
                     Selection.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
                 End If
           
        End Select
        t = t + 1
    Next Sheet
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

### Import Table Values

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub ImportData()

    Dim Exceptions(): Exceptions = Array("LoginData", "Weekly Spread (%)", _
        "Weekly spread (Count)Summary", "Sheet1", "Consolidated_Data")
    
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    
    Dim dws As Worksheet: Set dws = wb.Sheets("LoginData")
    'dws.Cells.Clear ' clear previous data
    Dim dCell As Range: Set dCell = dws.Range("A1") ' first
    
    Dim sws As Worksheet, srg As Range, IsFirstFound As Boolean

    For Each sws In wb.Worksheets ' '.Sheets' would include charts!
        If IsError(Application.Match(sws.Name, Exceptions, 0)) Then ' not found
            If IsFirstFound Then ' it's not the first; exclude headers
                With sws.Range("A1").CurrentRegion
                    Set srg = .Resize(.Rows.Count - 1).Offset(1)
                End With
            Else ' it's the first; include headers
                Set srg = sws.Range("A1").CurrentRegion
                IsFirstFound = True
            End If
            dCell.Resize(srg.Rows.Count, srg.Columns.Count).Value = srg.Value
            Set dCell = dCell.Offset(srg.Rows.Count) ' next
        'Else ' found; it's one from the exceptions array; do nothing
        End If
    Next sws

    MsgBox "Data imported into """ & dws.Name & """.", vbInformation

End Sub
```

**Some Thoughts on Your Code**

```
Sub s()
    ' Next time show us the variable declarations and the For Each...Next loop.
    
    Dim Sheet As Worksheet
    Dim t As Long ' it is already 0; my code uses a boolean 'IsFirstFound'.
    
    For Each Sheet In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        
        Select Case Sheet
        ' This was a major mistake. Also, 'LoginData' had to be included.
        ' Also, keep in mind that this is case sensitive i.e. e.g. 'sheet1'
        ' will not be excluded. In my code 'Application.Match' is used
        ' on an array of the names which is not case sensitive.
        Case "LoginData", "Weekly Spread (%)", _
            "Weekly spread (Count)Summary", "Sheet1", "Consolidated_Data"
        
        Case Else
            ' No need to use 'Select'. Use the 'With' statement instead.
            ' Best use variables to reference the workbook, worksheets
            ' and ranges. See 'wb', 'sws', 'dws', 'srg' and 'dCell' in my code.
            ' You needed to switch 'A1' and 'A2', or use 'If t = 0 Then'.
            ' It is very risky to use 'xlToRight' and 'xlDown' with 'A2' i.e.
            ' if a single cell in row 2 is empty, the wrong range
            ' will be referenced. The same goes for 'xlDown' in column 'A'
            ' while pasting.
            ' See the use of 'CurrentRegion', 'Resize' and 'Offset' in my code.
            ' Copying by assignment is faster and doesn't mess with
            ' the selection like 'PasteSpecial' does.
            
            ' The following two blocks of code are highly unreliable.
            ' You could call it a first step in getting rid of 'Select'.
            
            With Sheet
                If t = 0 Then ' first worksheet
                    .Range(.Range("A1"), .Range("A1").End(xlToRight).End(xlDown)).Copy
                Else ' all but the first worksheet
                    .Range(.Range("A2"), .Range("A2").End(xlToRight).End(xlDown)).Copy
                End If
            End With
            
            With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("LoginData")
                If t = 0 Then ' first worksheet
                    .Range("A1").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
                Else ' all but the first worksheet
                    .Range("A1").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
                End If
            End With
        
        End Select
        
        t = 1 ' since 'If T = 0 Then' is used (switches to all but the first)
    
    Next Sheet

    ' There are too many issues for such a code to be reliable!
    ' It will work until it doesn't which may be sooner than you expect.

End Sub
```